# Electrostatic force between a charged non conducting half cylinder and dielectric sheet

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I know how to calculate an electric force on a point charge due to a continuous body. But is there any way to calculate electric force of a continuous body on a continuous body. So is this question:

> A half cylinder of radius R and length L >> R is formed by cutting a cylindrical pipe made of an insulating material along a plane containing its axis. The rectangular base of the half cylinder is closed by a dielectric plate of length of length L and width 2R. A charge Q on the half cylinder and a charge q on the dielectric plate are uniformly sprinkled. Find the electrostatic force between the plate and the half cylinder.

I think we have to do double integration or so. Please help me in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you know how to calculate the force on a poitn charge $q$ due to a continuous body...

then... you have to sum up (integrate) the forces over all the $dq$s of the second body.

However, this is quite difficult and it's not often done. It's quite easy to calculate the force on a charge q due to a charged circle. But the force between two circles is really hard, and it is done numerically by computers.

However, you have to think if you really need this calculation: can it be approximated?

Comment: Yes you could make an approximation and please show it numerically.

Comment: Please give the question a proper title like 'electrostatic force between cylinder and plane'. 'Difficult question' is not one

Comment: I have given a proper title